# Remove special char and albhabets and space from string using vb.net

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [split special character and alphabets from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402830/split-special-character-and-alphabets-from-a-string)

Am having a string .i would like to delete all special char ,alphabets and space from taht string. but am not able to get it.

```
my code
-------
  Dim str1 As String = "!@!@#!$@#$#123456habAB^*^&(*)(_)()*("
    Dim str2 As String = Regex.Replace(str1, "[\[\]\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\}%,;><!@#&\-\+]", "")

    MsgBox(str2)

am getting the result like
--------------------------
123456habAB_


expected result
---------------
123456
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using \D in your regex, matching anything that is not a digit.

Comment: i want only display  only digit.if i use \d it remove the digits.