# split special character and alphabets from a string

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

am having a string value . I contain the combination of alphbets, special char and numbers and whitspace. but i want to retrieve only numbers.

```
my code
-------
Dim str1 As String = "!@!@#!$@#$#123456habAB^*^&(*)(_)()*("
    Dim str2 As String = Regex.Replace(str1, "[\[\]\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\}%,;><!@#&\-\+/d]", "")

    MsgBox(str2)


output am getting
-----------------
123456habAB_

expected output
---------------
123456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, short and simple:

```
Dim str1 As String = "!@!@#!$@#$#123456habAB^*^&(*)(_)()*("
Dim str2 As String = Regex.Replace(str1, "[^\d]", "")

MsgBox(str2)
```

The problem with your solution was you did not replace "_" or alphabets with empty string. Its easier to replace all non numbers from a string than replacing all characters explicitly.